# Use jquery autocomplete in foreach

Tags: jquery, loops, autocomplete

I want to use jquery autocomplete in a foreach loop.

When using ids, only the first line would work with autocomplete:
[JSFiddle with IDs](http://jsfiddle.net/thebino/zBehW/2/)

The Second Method is to use class, but there would ALL fields overwritten

I found a third one, wich clone something:
[JSFiddle with clone](http://jsfiddle.net/thebino/5dzaK/1/)

How can i Change the "description" in the third one?
Or has somebody the right js/jquery experience to solve my problem?

I need the Loop arround the lines because the lines are dynamicaly

Comment: You can find the Second Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/thebino/EA55T/

Comment: I vote to close because both the question and the answer have no code but just links to fiddles. This question should be deleted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your elements unique id's and select the elements by these id's.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EA55T/1/)